# How to create a popup using Google Apps Script only if a certain button is pushed on the previous popup and remove text box?

Tags: loops, user-interface, google-apps-script, google-sheets, prompt

My code below opens 4 text boxes, 1 asking a YES/NO question and 3 asking OK/CANCEL questions. Every one of them accepts text, but I want the first question to only accept buttons YES and NO without a text box. Also, if the answer to the first question is NO, I want it to skip the second question and go straight to the third question.

Questions are as follows:

- Did we do work for this client today/yesterday? [YES/NO]
- What did we help this client with today? [textbox][OK/CANCEL] ***skip if previous answer is no
- When should we follow up with this client next? (MM/DD/YY) [textbox][OK/CANCEL]
- Next Follow Up Activity? [textbox][OK/CANCEL]

```
function TextBox() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1JZ-v5n5m0_lyaoLgsHDAa78AtYNP5AsUDo2NRpJbwG4').getSheetByName('HOT & WARM CLIENTS');
  sheet.sort(9)

  var today = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-6", "MM/dd/yy")
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var valuesToCopy = sheet.getRange("C5:J5").getDisplayValues().map(r => r.join(' \n '));

var ar2 = [
{
  message: valuesToCopy + "\n\n Did we do work for this client today/yesterday? (YES/NO)",
  range: "G5"
}

];

var ar3 = [
    
    { // promptUPDATE3
      message: valuesToCopy + "\n\n What did we help this client with today?",
      range: "H5"
    },
    
  ];

var ar = [
    // { // promptUPDATE3
    //   message: valuesToCopy + "\n\n What did we help this client with today?",
    //   range: "PREVIOUS"
    // },
    { // promptUPDATE
      message: valuesToCopy + "\n\n When should we follow up with this client next? (MM/DD/YY)",
      range: "I5"
    },
    { // promptUPDATE2
      message: valuesToCopy + "\n\n Next Follow Up Activity?",
      range: "J5"
    }
  ];

ar2.forEach(({message, range }) => {
  var res = ui.prompt(message, ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
  if (res.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.YES) {
    sheet.getRange("G5").setValue(today);

  } else { 
    Logger.log('The user clicked "No" or the dialog\'s close button.');
  }
})


  ar3.forEach(({ message, range }) => {
    var res = ui.prompt(message, ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
    var lastRowSourceData = sheet.getRange("H5").getValue();
    var lastActivity = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1JZ-v5n5m0_lyaoLgsHDAa78AtYNP5AsUDo2NRpJbwG4').getSheetByName('HOT & WARM CLIENTS').getRange("H5").getValue();
    if (res.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.OK) {
      sheet.getRange(range).setValue(lastActivity+" | "+res.getResponseText());
    } else {
      Logger.log('The user clicked "No" or the dialog\'s close button.');
    }
  })



  ar.forEach(({ message, range }) => {
    var res = ui.prompt(message, ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
    if (res.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.OK) {
      sheet.getRange(range).setValue(res.getResponseText());

    } else {
      Logger.log('The user clicked "No" or the dialog\'s close button.');
    }
  })
  
  }
```

Comment: Do you run your script in another `spreadsheet` file? Also, please share some test spreadsheet where we can replicate your script easily. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Here is a test spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nOuT_WFXUh4XqUiub1G-dkngpm12RBSHblttUNx6sp8/edit#gid=0 please note the frozen rows. 

I don't understand your question about running in another spreadsheet file, can you please clarify? My script runs from Extensions > Apps Script

Comment: Thanks for your response. I was asking if you're running your script in a different spreadsheet because your have a line with `SpreadsheetApp.openById('1JZ-v5n5m0_lyaoLgsHDAa78AtYNP5AsUDo2NRpJbwG4').getSheetByName('HOT & WARM CLIENTS');` which looks like your script isn't bound to your actual spreadsheet file.

Comment: What are the benefits of having it bound?

Comment: One of the main benefits is shorter use of code, you can instead use `getActiveSpreadsheet()` since it is already a bound script to the spreadsheet file. E.g. `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('HOT & WARM CLIENTS');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## *SUGGESTION* *[SCRIPT UPDATED]*

Perhaps you can try this tweaked script below. This will use the `alert` Class Ui method for the first question & an `if condition` to skip the order of questions if the user selects `NO`.

In my understanding, here is the flow you want to achieve:

1. The ***first question*** should not have a **`Textbox`** but only give the user to select `YES` or `NO` buttons.
2. If user selects `NO` on the ***first question***, route the user to the ***third question*** instead.
3. Otherwise, the user will be prompted with the questions in order.

> *NOTE: This sample script will only process the **first** client on your sheet **just like** on your actual script. If I have misunderstood something **Or** if there's anything else missing, feel free to let me know.*

### *Sample Tweaked Script*

```
function TextBox() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var today = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-6", "MM/dd/yy");
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('HOT & WARM CLIENTS');
  sheet.sort(9);
  var sheetData = sheet.getRange("C5:J5").getDisplayValues();
  var questions = [['\n\n Did we do work for this client today/yesterday? (YES/NO)', "G"],
  ['\n\n What did we help this client with today?', "H"],
  ['\n\n When should we follow up with this client next? (MM/DD/YY)', "I"],
  ['\n\n Next Follow Up Activity?', "J"]];


  var row = "5"; //ONLY process current client on 5th row
  var clientDetails = sheetData[0].join('\n');

  /**First question */
  var q1 = ui.alert(clientDetails + questions[0][0], ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO)
  if (q1 == ui.Button.YES) {
    sheet.getRange(questions[0][1] + row).setValue(today);
    /**End of the First question */

    /**Second question */
    var q2 = ui.prompt(clientDetails + questions[1][0], ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
    var lastActivity = sheet.getRange(questions[1][1] + row).getValue();
    q2.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.OK ? sheet.getRange(questions[1][1] + row).setValue(lastActivity + " | " + q2.getResponseText()) : console.log('The user clicked "No" or the dialog\'s close button.');
    /**End of the Second question*/

    /**Third question */
    var q3 = ui.prompt(clientDetails + questions[2][0], ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
    q3.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.OK ? sheet.getRange(questions[2][1] + row).setValue(q3.getResponseText()) : console.log('The user clicked "No" or the dialog\'s close button.');
    /**End of the Third question*/

    /**Fourth question */
    var q4 = ui.prompt(clientDetails + questions[3][0], ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
    q4.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.OK ? sheet.getRange(questions[3][1] + row).setValue(q4.getResponseText()) : console.log('The user clicked "No" or the dialog\'s close button.');
    /**End of the Fourth question*/
  } else {
    /**Skip to the third question if 'NO' was selected on the first question*/
    var q3 = ui.prompt(clientDetails + questions[2][0], ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
    q3.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.OK ? sheet.getRange(questions[2][1] + row).setValue(q3.getResponseText()) : console.log('The user clicked "No" or the dialog\'s close button.');

    /**End to fourth question*/
    var q4 = ui.prompt(clientDetails + questions[3][0], ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
    q4.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.OK ? sheet.getRange(questions[3][1] + row).setValue(q4.getResponseText()) : console.log('The user clicked "No" or the dialog\'s close button.');

  }
}
```

### *Demonstration*

*- Quick Test*

[image]

*- E.g. If the user selects `NO` on the `first question` & then gets skipped to the `third question`*

[image]

### *References*

- [alert(prompt, buttons)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui#alertprompt,-buttons)

Comment: Two questions: First, I would like the scenario where the client clicks NO for the first question to skip to the third question like your code does, but also to go to the fourth question. Your code seems to skip the fourth question too. I tried moving var q4... into the else statement but that did not work for me for some reason. 

Second, with your code on the test sheet it properly processes the first client on the list, but with my actual client spreadsheet it processes a seemingly random client on a different row. Do you know why that may be?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I see. I thought you only want to go to the 3rd question once `No` is selected. Moving forward, please be more specific with your actual goal, like include a **step-by-step flow you actually want to achieve**. That way, everything's clear for everyone. Updated my script.  As for your second question,  that is happening as apparently your original code contains `sheet.sort(9);` which sorts the client in random order. So in reality, you want the script to process each client in order, correct?

Comment: I thought `sheet.sort(9);` would sort the data in ascending order by column 9? I want the script to process whatever client is in row 5, which should be the client that has the earliest date in column 9 (Date of Next Activity)

Right now when I run your code it works perfectly in the test script, but my actual database has more data in columns K-AP that I don't want the script to bring into the textbox, which is why I tried `var valuesToCopy = sheet.getRange("C5:J5").getDisplayValues().map(r => r.join(' \n '));`. Also, it keeps processing someone in row 245 instead of row 5

Comment: I see. Updated my script. If we were able to help you with your question, you may want to click the accept/up-vote button on the left (check icon). By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the similar concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved. That way, they'll be easily recommended to your post on their searches without the need of posting a duplicate question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think putting comments inside you objects is a good idea

Try it this way:

```
function lfunko() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1JZ-v5n5m0_lyaoLgsHDAa78AtYNP5AsUDo2NRpJbwG4').getSheetByName('HOT & WARM CLIENTS');
  sheet.sort(9)
  var today = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-6", "MM/dd/yy")
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var valuesToCopy = sheet.getRange("C5:J5").getDisplayValues().flat().map(r => r.join(' \n '));
  var ar2 = [{ message: valuesToCopy + "\n\n Did we do work for this client today/yesterday? (YES/NO)", range: "G5" }];
  var ar3 = [{ message: valuesToCopy + "\n\n What did we help this client with today?", range: "H5" }];
  var ar = [{ message: valuesToCopy + "\n\n What did we help this client with today?", range: "PREVIOUS" }, { message: valuesToCopy + "\n\n When should we follow up with this client next? (MM/DD/YY)", range: "I5" }, { message: valuesToCopy + "\n\n Next Follow Up Activity?", range: "J5" }];
  ar2.forEach(obj => {
    var res = ui.prompt(obj.message, ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
    if (res.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.YES) {
      sheet.getRange("G5").setValue(today);

    } else {
      Logger.log('The user clicked "No" or the dialog\'s close button.');
    }
  });
  ar3.forEach(obj => {
    var res = ui.prompt(obj.message, ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
    var lastRowSourceData = sheet.getRange("H5").getValue();
    var lastActivity = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1JZ-v5n5m0_lyaoLgsHDAa78AtYNP5AsUDo2NRpJbwG4').getSheetByName('HOT & WARM CLIENTS').getRange("H5").getValue();
    if (res.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.OK) {
      sheet.getRange(range).setValue(lastActivity + " | " + res.getResponseText());
    } else {
      Logger.log('The user clicked "No" or the dialog\'s close button.');
    }
  });
  ar.forEach((obj) => {
    var res = ui.prompt(obj.message, ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
    if (res.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.OK) {
      sheet.getRange(obj.range).setValue(res.getResponseText());

    } else {
      Logger.log('The user clicked "No" or the dialog\'s close button.');
    }
  });
}
```

And the UI does not contain any drop down selections.  You would have to build one with html.

Comment: I ran your code and the textbox is still there in the first popup, and the second question pops up twice when I click NO instead of not at all. But thank you very much for reconfiguring the code.

Comment: Yeah but the reality is that you are going to have to do this by building your own html modeless dialog.  I was simply pointing out that putting comments inside of objects is not a good idea